# Trying to make simple PDF document with Apache poi

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I see the internet is riddled with people complaining about apache's pdf products, but I cannot find my particular usecase here. I am trying to do a simple Hello World with apache poi. Right now my code is as follows:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream export() throws IOException {
    //Blank Document
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

    //Write the Document in file system
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();;

    //create table
    XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
    XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
    styles.setSpellingLanguage("English");
    //create first row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
    tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

    //create second row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
    tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
    tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
    tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

    //create third row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
    tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
    tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
    tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

    PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
    out.close();
    return out;
}
```

and the code that calls this is:

```
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> convertToPDFPost(@ApiParam(value = "DTOs passed from the FE" ,required=true )  @Valid @RequestBody ExportEnvelopeDTO exportDtos) {

        if (exportDtos.getProdExportDTOs() != null) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/kornhaus/Desktop/test.pdf");
                out.write(exporter.export().toByteArray());
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(responseFile, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

On this line here: `out.write(exporter.export().toByteArray());`
 the code throws an exception:

```
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse xml bean
```

I have no clue what's causing this, where to even look for this kind of documentation. I have been coding a decade plus and never had such difficulty with what should be a simple Java library. Any help would be great.

Comment: Not clear why you are downvoting my answer. It is tested and works. Of course it is only a draft to show the principle. It is not a ready to use code. And to reduce the memory usage the created Word document could be saved as a temporary file instead holding it's bytes in memory.

Answer (score 22):

The main problem with this is that those `PdfOptions` and `PdfConverter` are not part of the `apache poi` project. They are developed by `opensagres` and first versions were badly named `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions` and `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter`. Those old classes were not updated since 2014 and needs version `3.9`  of  `apache poi` to be used.

But the same developers provide [fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/2.0.1), which is much more current and works using the latest stable release `apache poi 3.17`. So we should using this.

But since even those newer `PdfOptions` and `PdfConverter` are not part of the `apache poi` project, `apache poi` will not testing those with their releases. And so the default `*.docx` documents created by `apache poi` lacks some content which `PdfConverter` needs.

1. There must be a styles document, even if it is empty.
2. There must be section properties for the page having at least the page size set.
3. Tables must have a table grid set.

To fulfilling this we must add some code additionally in our program. Unfortunately this then needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in [Faq-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

And because we need changing the underlaying low level objects, the document must be written so underlaying objects will be committed. Else the `XWPFDocument` which we hand over the `PdfConverter` will be incomplete.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

//needed jars: fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core-2.0.1.jar, 
//             fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-2.0.1.jar,
//             fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-2.0.1.jar,
//             itext-2.1.7.jar                                  
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;

//needed jars: apache poi and it's dependencies
//             and additionally: ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class XWPFToPDFConverterSampleMin {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // there must be a styles document, even if it is empty
  XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();

  // there must be section properties for the page having at least the page size set
  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
  pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(12240)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
  pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(15840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"

  // filling the body
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

  //create first row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
  tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
  tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
  tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice and PdfConverter to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  //first column = 2 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  //other columns (2 in this case) also each 2 inches width
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  }

  //create second row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
  tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
  tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
  tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

  //create third row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
  tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
  tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
  tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //trying picture
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The picture in line: ");
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(30));
  in.close();  
  run.setText(" text after the picture.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //document must be written so underlaaying objects will be committed
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  document.write(out);
  document.close();

  document = new XWPFDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
  PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
  PdfConverter converter = (PdfConverter)PdfConverter.getInstance();
  converter.convert(document, new FileOutputStream("XWPFToPDFConverterSampleMin.pdf"), options);

  document.close();

 }
}
```

---

**Using XDocReport**

Another way would be using the newest version of [opensagres/xdocreport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport) as described in [Converter only with ConverterRegistry](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/Converters#converter-only-with-converterregistry):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

//needed jars: xdocreport-2.0.1.jar, 
//             odfdom-java-0.8.7.jar,
//             itext-2.1.7.jar  
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.Options;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.IConverter;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterRegistry;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterTypeTo;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.document.DocumentKind;

//needed jars: apache poi and it's dependencies
//             and additionally: ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar 
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class XWPFToPDFXDocReport {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // there must be a styles document, even if it is empty
  XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();

  // there must be section properties for the page having at least the page size set
  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
  pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(12240)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
  pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(15840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"

  // filling the body
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

  //create first row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
  tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
  tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
  tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice and PdfConverter to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  //first column = 2 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  //other columns (2 in this case) also each 2 inches width
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  }

  //create second row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
  tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
  tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
  tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

  //create third row
  XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
  tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
  tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
  tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //trying picture
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The picture in line: ");
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(30));
  in.close();  
  run.setText(" text after the picture.");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //document must be written so underlaaying objects will be committed
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  document.write(out);
  document.close();

  // 1) Create options DOCX 2 PDF to select well converter form the registry
  Options options = Options.getFrom(DocumentKind.DOCX).to(ConverterTypeTo.PDF);

  // 2) Get the converter from the registry
  IConverter converter = ConverterRegistry.getRegistry().getConverter(options);

  // 3) Convert DOCX 2 PDF
  InputStream docxin= new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
  OutputStream pdfout = new FileOutputStream(new File("XWPFToPDFXDocReport.pdf"));
  converter.convert(docxin, pdfout, options);

  docxin.close();       
  pdfout.close();       
 
 }
}
```

---

October 2018:
This code works using `apache poi 3.17`. It cannot work using `apache poi 4.0.0` due to changings in `apache poi` which were not taken in account until now in `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter` as well as in `fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter`.

---

February 2019:
Works for me now using the newest `apache poi` version `4.0.1` and the newest version `2.0.2` of [fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/2.0.2) and consorts.

---

June 2021:
Works using `apache poi` version `4.1.2` and the newest version `2.0.2` of [fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/2.0.2) and consorts.
Cannot work using `apache poi` version `5.0.0` because `XDocReport` needs `ooxml-schemas` which `apache poi 5` does not support anymore.

---

April 2022:
Works using `apache poi` version `5.2.2` and the newest version `2.0.3` of [fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/2.0.3) and consorts.