# Convert docx in pdf wrong

Tags: java, pdf, java-8, apache-poi, docx

I need to convert docx in pdf and my code is this:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(originalPathSource));
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

        OutputStream out = null;
        try {

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(targetFileName));
        
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(docx, out, options);
```

the libraries are these:

```
<properties>
        <versioniApache>4.0.1</versioniApache>
        <versioniApachePDF>1.0.6</versioniApachePDF>
        <versioniApacheSchema>4.1.2</versioniApacheSchema>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${versioniApache}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${versioniApache}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${versioniApache}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
            <version>${versioniApachePDF}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
            <version>${versioniApachePDF}</version>
        </dependency>
```

The problem is when the programs exetuce pdfConvert it gives me this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocumentPart     at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.getFontsDocument(XWPFStylesDocument.java:1477)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.(XWPFStylesDocument.java:190)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.(XWPFStylesDocument.java:184)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.createStylesDocument(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:159)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.(PdfMapper.java:149)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:55)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)
> at apachePoi.apachePoiMain.convertiPDF(apachePoiMain.java:137)  at
> apachePoi.apachePoiMain.main(apachePoiMain.java:111) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 11 more

Anyone can help me to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache POI exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339378/apache-poi-exception)

Comment: You are mixing `apche poi` versions, `4.0.1` with `4.1.2`. [Don't do that as it is not supported.](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204). Also version `1.0.6` of `fr.opensagres.xdocreport` is to old for `apache poi 4`. Version `2.0.2` needs to be used.