# Error in Docx to PDF conversion using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to convert word doc (docx) to pdf using apache poi library but am getting following error:

> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: string
>   value 'end' is not a valid enumeration value for ST_Jc in namespace
>   http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main

This is my code snippet:

```
          FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(inputFile);
          XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(in);
          File outFile=new File(outputFile);
          OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(outFile);
          PdfOptions options=null;
          PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document,out,options);
```

The document that am trying to convert is 2.9 MB and contains tables, images.

Apache poi dependencies that am using are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have gone through many posts related to this but didn’t got any solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440312/docx-to-pdf-converter-in-java/51440649#51440649

Comment: You are using an old version of Apache POI, and an incorrect + misnamed versin of xdocreport. Upgrade both!