# Apache POI - convert word to pdf

Tags: pdf, ms-word, apache-poi, converters

I am trying to convert XWPFDocument to PDF but getting an error. I am using - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/2.0.1.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport     /fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf -->
<dependency>
<groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
<artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
   FileInputStream fis   = new FileInputStream("1.docx");

   XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = xdoc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontFamily("Arial");
        run.setText("this is a test");

   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File(dir + filename));          
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        // 3) Convert XWPFDocument to Pdf
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(xdoc, out, options);
```

I am getting this error. does anybody knows why?

```
fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:71)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:39)
at fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:46)
```

Upgrading to version 2.0.2 of maven dependency solved the problem but now I am getting this error when opening the pdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PigXk.png)

[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzWT.png)

Comment: The `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.` version `2.0.1` works using `apache poi 3.x`. Using `apache poi 4.x`, `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.` version `2.0.2` is needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440312/docx-to-pdf-converter-in-java/51440649#51440649.

Comment: thank you . Upgrading to version 2.0.2 of maven dependency solved the problem but now I am getting this error when opening the pdf. image attached above

Comment: According the error "Unable to open the file. A sharing violation has occurred.", the file is opened already using exclusive locking. Something locks the created `PDF` file. Make sure you closed the `FileOutputStream out`.

Comment: yes . outputstream and other xwpf documents are closed. when I closed the IDE to test the file, it became invalid.

Comment: upon building . I got the error above . updated image

Comment: This is a total different question now. I recommend deletion this question and asking a new one about the new issue. But please do not provide code or stack traces as pictures. And please provide all necessary code. What is `MainApp.mergeDocument` doing? I suspect it simply concatenates multiple `Word` document bodies. This is not correct according the specs of `Office Open XML`. `MS Word` will tolerate this but other libraries which are following the specs of `Office Open XML` might not tolerate this.

Comment: the main goal of the application is to merge all documents from a specific folder and convert it to pdf file. that is the main function of mergeDocument

Comment: but for now. I am trying to convert a single word document to a pdf file for testing purposes before leaping to next step

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that nobody will be able reproducing your issue. In general the code of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440312/docx-to-pdf-converter-in-java/51440649#51440649 works.

Comment: please see this - I tried to make it as clear as I could hoping I could deliver the point. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017210/merging-two-document-and-convert-to-pdf-apache-poi

Comment: @Axel Richter: thank you, it works!