# How to wrap contents in a table ? .docx to PDF using apache POI

Tags: pdf, apache-poi, xwpf, pdftables

On converting the .docx to PDF using apache POI, the contents in the table are not getting wrapped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPKyK.png)

Following is the code , I am using to convert

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
                                
                                PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
                                
                                PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, output, options);
```

Comment: `PdfOptions` and `PdfConverter` are not `apache poi` classes. They are from [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport). What versions are you using? Also what version of `apache poi` `XWPFDocument` is used? For me this is not reproducible using latest  versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440312/docx-to-pdf-converter-in-java/51440649#51440649.

Comment: @AxelRichter I am using the versions apache poi version 4.1.2 fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf 2.0.2 and itext-4.2.1. Yet I am facing this Issue. Is that something I am missing? Kindly guide me

Comment: I suspect this is a problem in the `*.docx` file then. We would need this file to ba able to help.