Update the form field in docx
I have a word document in docx format. I create it as a form with multiple form fields. I would like to update the form fields programatically using Apache POI. When I browsed, i found some places where they recommend to use XWPFFormField. I am not finding it in poi-ooxml-{version}.jar. Is there any other alternative?
Tried using Apache POI but could not find solution.

What kind of form fields? If legacy form fields see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409262/problem-with-processing-word-document-java/56412311#56412311.

I am not using the legacy form fields, I am using  Rich Text Content Control & Plain Text Content Control.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996325/how-to-replace-wsdt-xml-in-word-doc-using-apache-poi-as-xwpfsdt-and-xwpfsdtco/73005126#73005126 for content controls.
