# dependency probem ( Apache POI)

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, apache-poi, docx

I have an arabic docx file , I want to convert it to pdf , so I m using Apache Poi as a tool , but it keep showing me always java.lang.NoSuchMethodError , I think the version of Apache POI used in my project is not compatible :

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440312/docx-to-pdf-converter-in-java/51440649#51440649