# ApachePOI pdf creation

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a simple table with ApachePOI in a maven project. I looked in their documentation but I didn't see a dependency for PDFs. Is there a built in way in ApachePOI do to create a PDF?

I saw this tutorial that it teaches you how to convert the file but not how to create one from scratch.
https://rdtschools.com/covert-docx-file-pdf-using-apache-poi-library-java/

Then I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330192/trying-to-make-simple-pdf-document-with-apache-poi) on stackoverflow, and the answer make it seem like using using [Opensagres POI](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf/2.0.1) is the way to go since it works with Apache POI 3.17, but requires another JAR.

Comment: If you want to programatically create a .pdf from scratch - and if you're uninterested in working with Microsoft documents - then maybe ApachePOI isn't the right library for you.

Comment: @paulsm4 That's a very interesting feedback. Do you think PDFBox is a better approach then? or what do you suggest (we can't use iText). Is there a good tutorial on how to create a pdf using microsoft products like excel to pdf using apache POI?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create pdf file, you can try

```
new FileOutputStream("path.pdf");
```

And then using pdf writer, write this to file.
But if you are interested in Pdf table generation. I would like to offer you another lib.

I worked with **itextpdf**, and created table in pdf documents.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.tool/xmlworker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

You should write something like this

```
public PdfStream opendocument() {
    document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
        document.open();
    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this;
}
```

p.s. it's part from my code, don't care about **PdfStream** class.

Where **writer** and **document** objects are **PdfWriter** and **Document** instances.
I think that write all code example here, it isn't good idea, but you can read more about this https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1

If you have some questions, ask me) Good luck !

Comment: We currently use iText where I work, but we use an old version. The new version cost money. Do you know another open source tool besides Apache POI and PDFbox I could use? Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer