# Exporting PDF document from Apache POI XWPFDocument document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a word document (XWPFDocument) with Apache POI and want to 
convert it to pdf.

This is my code:

```
String wordFilename = "report.docx";
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(); 
//...document content code here
document.write(output);
document.close();
```

I have seen some other implementations but all of them are using FileInputStream and get the document from a file. In my case I have a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bytes written from `XWPFDocument` will always be `*.docx` format. So at first you will need a DOCX to PDF converter. So what DOCX to PDF converter are you using?

Comment: @AxelRichter org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf

Comment: Yes, so? What is the problem then? Convert it. JSF and Omnifaces have nothing to do with this.

Comment: The `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf ` is outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330192/trying-to-make-simple-pdf-document-with-apache-poi/51337157#51337157. Note this works using `apache poi 3.17`. There is nothing working with `apache poi 4.0.0` until now.