# how to save xwpfdocument as a pdf

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

I have a project that creating ms word document via xwpfdocument. I want to save the document as a pdf document. To do this I wrote this codes.

```
        FileOutputStream output2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(word_saveas_file+SalesOrder+"_"+type+"_Report.pdf"));
        PdfOptions options=PdfOptions.create();
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, output2, options);
```

I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1182)
    at Servlet.shop_visit_report.doGet(shop_visit_report.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I added this .jar's to my project

```
-org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar
-org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.6.jar
-fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-2.0.0.jar
-itext-2.1.7.jar
-ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar
```

Comment: Complete working examples having used `jar`s mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330192/trying-to-make-simple-pdf-document-with-apache-poi/51337157#51337157

Comment: You are using super old versions of the OpenSagres converter, with the wrong package names, upgrade!