# OpenPdf/PdfBox automatically generate table of contents

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext, pdfbox, openpdf

In my current java/springboot project, I need to create a PDF dynamicaly containing paragraphs, images and tables.
And I also need to add the table of content of this document.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically generate this table of contents using either openPdf or pdfBox.

I noticed that it is possible to do so using IText, but it is not free...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can integrate jasper report for your requirement. It is free

Comment: Hi @RajeshPatel, thanks for your quick answer, can you tell me more about jasper ?

Comment: JasperReports is LGPL and iText is AGPL (if that means free or not free for either of them, it will entirely depend on whether you need a commercial license, or can operate under the opensource license terms)

Comment: It's not possible in PDFBox. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Ps.: iText provides an example on [how to use events to do it](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/creating-table-of-contents-using-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenPDF for this:  https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF

Also see Flying Saucer: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer

Answer (score 0):

Actually neither openPdf nor pdfBox provide a way to automatically generate table of contents :-(

iText provide us with such functionality, but it is under AGPL licence so cannot be used in my case...

For the time being, I will try acheive my needs using apache POI then convert the generated docx to pdf using opensagres/xdocreport (see: [Trying to make simple PDF document with Apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337157/10514369))