# Apache POI Excel XLSX save as PDF

Tags: excel, spring, pdf, itext, apache-poi

Currently I work using Spring Framework. I was asked to print a report with a PDF output that retrieves data from a SQL database, but the project I'm working on has Apache POI installed where the output is Excel XLSX.
Is there a way to convert Excel XLSX format to PDF?
I already have Apache POI and recently added iTextPDF.

Apache POI

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

iTextPDF

```xml
    <properties>
        <itext.version>7.2.3</itext.version>
    </properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

EDIT : This is the code to generate XLSX file

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CTRL_REPORT_READ')")
    @ResponseBody
    public void download(@Valid @ModelAttribute ReportForm reportForm, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("IN: reimbursement/dowload report-POST");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            downloadExcel(reportForm, workbook);
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
            String fileName = "Reimbursement Report " + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".xlsx"; 
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occurs when add new data in method reimbursement with error message : " + e.getMessage());
            redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(AppDataConstant.ERROR_FLASH_RESP, "Download reimbursement report failed");
        } finally {
            if (workbook != null) {
                workbook.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank you very much before

Comment: [Apache POI 3.15 is over 6 years old and has loads of bugs](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.15) why are you using such an old version?

Comment: if you're looking for a solution within the itext ecosystem, [pdfOffice](https://itextpdf.com/products/itext-7/convert-ms-office-to-pdf-pdfoffice) does the trick (XLS to PDF).

Comment: re-reading your question, if the project is already using Apache POI to generate XLSX, I'm guessing it should be pretty trivial to generate PDFs. do you have the code that actually generates the XLSX files?

Comment: I'd probably look more into this direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337157/1566339

Comment: @Gagravarr because the project I'm working on already has Apache POI 3.15. Should I upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: @AndréLemos yes, I have the code. I'll edit my question to insert the code that generates the XLSX file and I will try the method you gave