# Apache POI docx to pdf SAXParseException: Premature End of File

Tags: kotlin, pdf, apache-poi, docx

I'm attempting to convert a docx file made in Apache POI to a pdf file. I've run into a couple of errors I haven't been able to resolve.

I'm using `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3` and `fr.opensages.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:1.0.6`

The code so far is as follows:

```kotlin
@GetMapping ("pdf")
fun getPdf (aResponse: HttpServletResponse) {

   val myDoc = XWPFDocument ()
   val myParagraph = myDoc.createParagraph ()
   val myRun = myParagraph.createRun ()
   myRun.setText ("Hello, world!")

   val myPdfOptions = PdfOptions.create ()

   aResponse.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
   aResponse.addHeader ("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"hello-world.pdf\"")

   aResponse.outputStream.use {
      PdfConverter.getInstance ().convert (myDoc, it, myPdfOptions)
   }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting one Styles document part, but found 0
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.getStyle(XWPFDocument.java:587)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.<init>(XWPFStylesDocument.java:190)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.styles.XWPFStylesDocument.<init>(XWPFStylesDocument.java:184)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.createStylesDocument(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:166)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.<init>(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:159)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.<init>(PdfMapper.java:149)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:55)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)
```

So next I added in an empty document styles into the document

```kotlin
   myDoc.createStyles ()
```

This errors with the following:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1013)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
   at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
   at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:2532)
   at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.lambda$parseToXmlObject$3(Locale.java:717)
   at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.syncWrap(Locale.java:490)
   at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:716)
   at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:233)
   at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.AbstractDocumentFactory.parse(AbstractDocumentFactory.java:71)
   at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.getStyle(XWPFDocument.java:591)
... continues same as above error
```

So far I haven't discovered a way around this last error. Maybe I am missing something in the Styles? It doesn't seem to like something with it's own `createStyles()` method.

Comment: Your `XWPFDocument` is too incomplete to convert it to PDF. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330192/trying-to-make-simple-pdf-document-with-apache-poi/51337157#51337157.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks that helps a lot. I got it working using the ConverterRegistry method. Is it expected though about the `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred (com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile)` message?

Comment: Yes. And the WARNING also tells what to do: `WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile$1`. Done already: https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues/420. No reaction since May 2020.